# Why does using a sparse matrix for least squares instead slow down the speed?

Tags: fitting, sparse-arrays

Here is the code. The matrix appears to be relatively sparse in terms of its visual representation, but why does using least squares result in significantly slower speed compared to the previously dense matrix?
(The code appears to be quite lengthy, but it only takes about two minutes to reproduce. I currently do not have a way to reduce it to a minimal example.)
May I ask why it causes the slowdown, and if there is any solution to it?
Thanks, Thanks.

```
test[t_, x_, y_] := 
  Sin[2 \[Pi] x] Sin[
    2 \[Pi] y] (2 Cos[Sqrt[(2 \[Pi]/5)^2 + (2 \[Pi]/4)^2] t 10] + 
     Sin[Sqrt[(2 \[Pi]/5)^2 + (2 \[Pi]/4)^2] t 10]);
deltau[t_, x_, y_] = 
  0.01 D[D[test[t, x, y], t], t] - 1/25 D[D[test[t, x, y], x], x] - 
   1/16 D[D[test[t, x, y], y], y];
deltaT[t_, x_, y_] = D[test[t, x, y], t];
deltau = 
  With[{code = deltau[t, x, y]}, 
   Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"]];
deltaT = 
  With[{code = deltaT[t, x, y]}, 
   Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"]];
test = With[{code = test[t, x, y]}, 
   Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"]];

(*CloseKernels[];
LaunchKernels[6];*)
(*$Pre=Function[Null,MemoryConstrained[#,1000000000-MemoryInUse[]],\
HoldAll];*)

dimension = 3;
n = 2.;
dn = (n)^dimension;(*和维数有关*)
dj = 50.;
(*dq=5.;*)
collocation = Tuples[Table[(i)/(n), {i, 0, n - 1}], dimension];
random1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];
random2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];
random3 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];
random4 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];
random5 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];




psi[i_, t_, x_, y_] := 1.(*f[i,1,x]*f[i,2,y]*);
li[i_, t_, x_, 
   y_] := {(t - (collocation[[i]][[1]] + 1/(2 n)))/
    Abs[1/(2 n)], (x - (collocation[[i]][[2]] + 1/(2 n)))/
    Abs[1/(2 n)], (y - (collocation[[i]][[3]] + 1/(2 n)))/
    Abs[1/(2 n)]};
phi[i_, j_, t_, x_, y_] := 
  Tanh[{random1[[i, j]], random2[[i, j]], random3[[i, j]]} . 
     li[i, t, x, y] + random5[[i, j]]];
df[t_, x_, y_] := 
  Table[phi[i, j, t, x, y]*psi[i, t, x, y], {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, dj}] //
    Flatten;
ddt[t_, x_, y_] = D[D[df[t, x, y], t], t]; // Timing
ddx[t_, x_, y_] = D[D[df[t, x, y], x], x];
ddy[t_, x_, y_] = D[D[df[t, x, y], y], y];

dd3[t_, x_, y_] = 
  1/100 ddt[t, x, y] - 1/25 ddx[t, x, y] - 1/16 ddy[t, x, y];

xdim = IntegerPart[dn dj];

funComptotal = 
   With[{code = N[dd3[t, x, y]]}, 
    Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, 
     CompilationTarget -> "C"]]; // AbsoluteTiming
funCompdf = 
   With[{code = N[df[t, x, y]]}, 
    Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, 
     CompilationTarget -> "C"]]; // AbsoluteTiming
funCompDt = 
  With[{code = N[D[df[t, x, y], t]]}, 
   Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"]];
funCompDx = 
  With[{code = N[D[df[t, x, y], x]]}, 
   Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"]];
funCompDy = 
  With[{code = N[D[df[t, x, y], y]]}, 
   Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"]];



dq = 20;
dQ = dq + 1;
omegapoint = 
  Table[Tuples[{Table[i/(n dq), {i, (j - 1) dq, j dq}], 
     Table[i/(n dq), {i, (k - 1) dq, k dq}], 
     Table[i/(n dq), {i, (p - 1) dq, p dq}]}], {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, 
    n}, {p, 1, n}];
omegapointbd5 = 
  Table[Tuples[{Table[(i - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}], 
     Table[(j - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}], 
     Table[(k - 1)/n, {z, 1}]}], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}];(*向t-x投影0*)
(*omegapointbd1=Table[{collocation[[i]][[1]]+(q-1)/(n \
dq),0.},{i,1,dn},{q,1,dQ}];*)
omegapointbd6 = 
  Table[Tuples[{Table[(i - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}], 
     Table[(j - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}], 
     Table[(k)/n, {z, 1}]}], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}];(*向t-x投影1*)
(*omegapointbd2=Table[{collocation[[i]][[1]]+(q-1)/(n \
dq),1.},{i,1,dn},{q,1,dQ}];*)
omegapointbd3 = 
  Table[Tuples[{Table[(i - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}], 
     Table[(j - 1)/n, {z, 1}], 
     Table[(k - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}]}], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k,
     n}];(*向t-y投影0*)

omegapointbd4 = 
  Table[Tuples[{Table[(i - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}], 
     Table[(j)/n, {z, 1}], 
     Table[(k - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}]}], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k,
     n}];(*向t-y投影1*)

omegapointbd1 = 
  Table[Tuples[{Table[(i - 1)/n, {z, 1}], 
     Table[(j - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}], 
     Table[(k - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}]}], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k,
     n}];(*向x-y投影0*)
omegapointbd2 = 
  Table[Tuples[{Table[(i)/n, {z, 1}], 
     Table[(j - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}], 
     Table[(k - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}]}], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k,
     n}];(*向x-y投影1*)



tabledfpoint = SparseArray[Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {(n dQ)^3}]];
tabledfpointbd1 = SparseArray[Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}]];
tabledfpointbd2 = SparseArray[Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}]];
tabledfpointbd3 = SparseArray[Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}]];
tabledfpointbd4 = SparseArray[Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}]];
tabledfpointbd5 = SparseArray[Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}]];
tabledfpointbd6 = SparseArray[Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}]];


Do[tabledfpoint[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^3 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^3, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]] = (Join @@ 
       Join @@ Join @@ 
         Table[funComptotal @@@ omegapoint[[i, j, k]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
           1, n}, {k, 1, 
           n}])[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^3 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^3, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 
    n}, {k, 1, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Do[If[ k == 1, 
   tabledfpointbd1[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]] = (Join @@ 
       Join @@ Join @@ 
         Table[funCompdf @@@ omegapointbd5[[i, j, k]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
           1, n}, {k, 1, 
           n}])[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 
   n}, {k, 1, n}];
Do[If[ k == n, 
   tabledfpointbd2[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]] = (Join @@ 
       Join @@ Join @@ 
         Table[funCompdf @@@ omegapointbd6[[i, j, k]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
           1, n}, {k, 1, 
           n}])[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 
   n}, {k, 1, n}];



Do[If[ i == 1, 
   tabledfpointbd5[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]] = (Join @@ 
       Join @@ Join @@ 
         Table[funCompdf @@@ omegapointbd1[[i, j, k]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
           1, n}, {k, 1, 
           n}])[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 
   n}, {k, 1, n}];
(*Do[If[ i==n,tabledfpointbd4[[((i-1)n+(j-1))dQ+1;;((i-1)n+j) \
dQ,((i-1)n+(j-1)) dj+1;;((i-1)n+j) \
dj]]=(Join@@Join@@Table[funCompDt@@@omegapointbd3[[i,j]],{i,1,n},{j,1,\
n}])[[((i-1)n+(j-1))dQ+1;;((i-1)n+j) dQ,((i-1)n+(j-1)) \
dj+1;;((i-1)n+j) dj]]],{i,1,n},{j,1,n}];*)
Do[If[ i == 1, 
   tabledfpointbd6[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]] = (Join @@ 
       Join @@ Join @@ 
         Table[funCompDt @@@ omegapointbd1[[i, j, k]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
           1, n}, {k, 1, 
           n}])[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 
   n}, {k, 1, n}];

Do[If[ j == 1, 
   tabledfpointbd3[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]] = (Join @@ 
       Join @@ Join @@ 
         Table[funCompdf @@@ omegapointbd3[[i, j, k]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
           1, n}, {k, 1, 
           n}])[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 
   n}, {k, 1, n}];
Do[If[ j == n, 
   tabledfpointbd4[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]] = (Join @@ 
       Join @@ Join @@ 
         Table[funCompdf @@@ omegapointbd4[[i, j, k]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
           1, n}, {k, 1, 
           n}])[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 
   n}, {k, 1, n}];


table0t = SparseArray[Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}]];
table1t = SparseArray[Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}]];
table0x = SparseArray[Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}]];
table1x = SparseArray[Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}]];
table0y = SparseArray[Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}]];
table1y = SparseArray[Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}]];


Do[If[i != 
    1, {table0t[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 2) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 2) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]] = -(funCompdf @@@ 
         omegapointbd1[[i, j, 
          k]])[[;; , ((i - 2) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
          1 ;; ((i - 2) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]], 
    table0t[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]] = (funCompdf @@@ 
        omegapointbd1[[i, j, 
         k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
         1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]],
    table1t[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 2) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 2) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]] = -(funCompDt @@@ 
         omegapointbd1[[i, j, 
          k]])[[;; , ((i - 2) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
          1 ;; ((i - 2) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]], 
    table1t[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]] = (funCompDt @@@ 
        omegapointbd1[[i, j, 
         k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
         1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]]}], {i, n}, {j, 
   n}, {k, n}];
Do[If[j != 
    1, {table0x[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 2) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 2) n + (k)) dj]] = -(funCompdf @@@ 
         omegapointbd3[[i, j, 
          k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 2) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
          1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 2) n + (k)) dj]], 
    table0x[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]] = (funCompdf @@@ 
        omegapointbd3[[i, j, 
         k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
         1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]],
    table1x[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 2) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 2) n + (k)) dj]] = -(funCompDx @@@ 
         omegapointbd3[[i, j, 
          k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 2) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
          1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 2) n + (k)) dj]], 
    table1x[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]] = (funCompDx @@@ 
        omegapointbd3[[i, j, 
         k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
         1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]]}], {i, n}, {j, 
   n}, {k, n}];
Do[If[k != 
    1, {table0y[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 2)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj]] = -(funCompdf @@@
          omegapointbd5[[i, j, 
          k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 2)) dj + 
          1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj]], 
    table0y[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]] = (funCompdf @@@ 
        omegapointbd5[[i, j, 
         k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
         1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]],
    table1y[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 2)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj]] = -(funCompDy @@@
          omegapointbd5[[i, j, 
          k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 2)) dj + 
          1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj]], 
    table1y[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]] = (funCompDy @@@ 
        omegapointbd5[[i, j, 
         k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
         1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]]}], {i, n}, {j, 
   n}, {k, n}];


joinjoin = 
  Join[tabledfpoint, tabledfpointbd1, tabledfpointbd2, 
   tabledfpointbd5, tabledfpointbd6, tabledfpointbd3, tabledfpointbd4,
    table0t, table0x, table0y, table1t, table1x, table1y];
lambda = N[100/Replace[Max /@ Abs[joinjoin], 0. -> Infinity, {1}]];
joinjoin = lambda*joinjoin;
point = SparseArray[Table[0., First[Dimensions[tabledfpoint]]]];
pointbd1 = 
  SparseArray[Table[0., First[Dimensions[tabledfpointbd1]]]];
pointbd2 = 
  SparseArray[Table[0., First[Dimensions[tabledfpointbd2]]]];
pointbd3 = 
  SparseArray[Table[0., First[Dimensions[tabledfpointbd3]]]];
pointbd4 = 
  SparseArray[Table[0., First[Dimensions[tabledfpointbd4]]]];
pointbd5 = 
  SparseArray[Table[0., First[Dimensions[tabledfpointbd5]]]];
pointbd6 = SparseArray[Table[0., First[Dimensions[tabledfpointbd6]]]];

t0t = SparseArray[Table[0., First[Dimensions[table0t]]]];
t1t = SparseArray[Table[0., First[Dimensions[table1t]]]];
t0x = SparseArray[Table[0., First[Dimensions[table0x]]]];
t1x = SparseArray[Table[0., First[Dimensions[table1x]]]];
t0y = SparseArray[Table[0., First[Dimensions[table0y]]]];
t1y = SparseArray[Table[0., First[Dimensions[table1y]]]];


Do[point[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^3 + 
      1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dQ^3]] = 
   deltau @@@ omegapoint[[i, j, k]], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}];
Do[If[ k == 1, 
   pointbd1[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dQ^2]] = 
    test @@@ omegapointbd5[[i, j, k]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, 
   n}];
Do[If[ k == n, 
   pointbd2[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dQ^2]] = 
    test @@@ omegapointbd6[[i, j, k]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, 
   n}];
Do[If[ j == 1, 
   pointbd3[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dQ^2]] = 
    test @@@ omegapointbd3[[i, j, k]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, 
   n}];
Do[If[ j == n, 
   pointbd4[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dQ^2]] = 
    test @@@ omegapointbd4[[i, j, k]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, 
   n}];
Do[If[ i == 1, 
   pointbd5[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dQ^2]] = 
    test @@@ omegapointbd1[[i, j, k]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, 
   n}];
Do[If[ i == 1, 
   pointbd6[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dQ^2]] = 
    deltaT @@@ omegapointbd1[[i, j, k]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1,
    n}];
f = Join[point, pointbd1, pointbd2, pointbd5, pointbd6, pointbd3, 
    pointbd4, t0t, t0x, t0y, t1t, t1x, t1y]*lambda;


LeastSquares[joinjoin, f]; // AbsoluteTiming
LeastSquares[Normal[joinjoin], Normal[f]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

[image]

May I ask why it causes the slowdown, and if there is any solution to it?
Thanks, Thanks.

Comment: Try generating a smaller set of matrices with similar structure annd random content, and see if you can reproduce the problem, then post that. Please do some troubleshooting on your own before dumping pages of code here.

Comment: You do `table0t = SparseArray[Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}]];` and then fill it with entries in a loop with `table0t [[i,j]] = [...]`This is not the way to create large sparse matrices. Please read the documentation in order to learn better ways of creating `SparseArrays`.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks,  if dq=10, the least squares for sparse matrix “joinjoin‘’ (about 3 seconds)is also slower than normal "joinjoin"(0.283116 seconds)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the matrix `joinjoin`: If you look at its the `SparseArray` box and then on the "+" sign, it tells you that its density is `0.114`. That's a very, very high density for many sparse matrix method. I am not sure, what exactly `LeastSquares` does (it comes with several method options), but I expect that direct methods, e.g., based on sparse QR decomposition (I think that's what is behind `Method-> "LSQR"` are used), and I am not surprised that they are not efficient here. Surprising to me is, that `Method -> "Direct"` actually impoves over the default method; but it is still slower than the dense matrix method.

Since you have many fewer variables than equations, I expect that your matrix `A = joinjoin` is injective. In that case you can solve the normal equation $A^T A x = A^T f$ with a *dense* matrix method instead:

```
A = joinjoin;
AT = Transpose[A];
x = LinearSolve[Normal[AT.A], AT.f, Method -> "Cholesky"]; // AbsoluteTiming //First
```

We use a dense matrix method here because `Transpose[A].A` has dimensions `{400,400}`.

> 0.006359

Comment: Thank you very much, using your method has indeed made the speed much faster.

Comment: You're welcome!